# What's the standard preprocessing / postprocessing workflow?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, sass, gruntjs

What's a more efficient way of doing things:

1. Have SASS files & separate CSS / JS files in your local environment, and have them compiled, concatenated, and minified after it's deployed.
2. Build & compile all files locally, and only push up the compiled, concatenated, and minified files to live.

I think #2 makes more sense from a performance angle, but it makes it less maintainable for projects that have multiple devs working on the same thing.

Is there a generally used solution for this problem?

Comment: That really depends on the scale of the project, the amount of developers, and whether or not you had coffee this morning. We can't answer this, because there is no single "right" way to do this.

Comment: I find [gruntjs](http://gruntjs.com/) helpful in making one-click workflows.

Comment: This is a question with no right answer, so is a bit off-topic. If you're doing small scale development, then do a project with each method and decide which one works best for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I keep both sources (such as SASS, CoffeeScript) and compiled / minified versions in the same repository.

Whenever I'm working on it, I have one or more processes open that look for changes in the files and start the relevant compilation procedures. This is so that whenever I test a change on a browser, it loads the final compiled / minified version. I do have to wait 1 or 2 seconds between hitting Save and hitting Reload on the browser, but IMHO the benefits I explain below offset this disadvantage.

Whenever I make a commit, it includes both changes to the sources and the relevant compiled/minified versions.

This has solved all problems for me, including:

1. All testing is done on the final compiled version, even during development, not on some different, half-baked version. This is particularly important for potentially damaging manipulations, such as Google Closure Compiler Advanced Compilation. (In fact, this development strategy is what has allowed me to use Advanced Compilation in the first place.)
2. Deployment on demo / test / production servers entails no compilation step, which could require different tools and versions than are available on those servers.

This is just my experience. It would probably need to be altered on really large projects, but for small- to medium-sized ones it works perfectly.